# How do I recognize if there was a change in data?

Tags: ios, swift

I need a visual indication if there was a change in the amount of data pulled from my database. Basically, if there were three rows when a user leaves the app but opens it again, and the app pulls data from the database and now there are 2 new rows with a total of 5 rows, I need to show a visual indication. Would I have to use core data to keep a counter?

Comment: What on earth do you imagine core data has to do with it???? If you need a fact (i.e. data), such as the previous row count, to persist from one run of your app to the next, store it in a file or use UserDefaults.

Answer (score 2):

1. Count the number of database rows in your `applicationWillResignActive` method. This method gets called when the user leaves your app.
2. Save that number to a file (or in your database somewhere).
3. Count the number of database rows in your `applicationDidBecomeActive` method.  This method gets called when your app starts up or resumes from background.
4. If they are different, show a notification.